# What tools can be appropriate to reverse engineer a (open-source) java program?

Tags: java

I am very new reverse engineering, and have the below mentioned tasks to achieve on a open source program called [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/). What (preferably free) tools can be appropriate to achieve these. I have been exploring Enterprise Architect for days and it has been pointed out to me it is not tool for such objectives.

- Extract different source code metrics such as LOC, Comments, No of classes etc.
- Extract abstract classes.
- Extract function calls
- Extract level of coupling between classes
- Extract different type of associations in classes.
- Extract different UML diagrams.
- Detect Singleton and Factory Method design patterns.
- Detect God Class and Lazy Class code smells.

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. I have heard this being referred to as reverse engineering, but to the best of my knowledge and my understanding of this site it's off-topic here. Either way, I'll defer to our community and let them decide if this question should be closed. Personally I'd suggest asking it on StackOverflow.